# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Relationship - User, Role, Pages and Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm developing kind of ACL for my application, using 4 tables:

[all tables and relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tznAF.png)

I can get the relationships for

1. users and roles:

   ```
   $user = App\Models\User::find( Auth::user()->id );
   //
   foreach( $user->roles as $user_role )
   ...
   ```
2. roles and pages:

   ```
   $roles = App\Models\Role::find( $user_role->id );
   //
   foreach( $roles->pages as $role_page )
   ...
   ```

But I'm stuck on last part, which is to get the permission for the pages that users has access. I don't know how.

---

I don't think that I make myself clear...

What I really need is, get the PERMISSIONS  for the pages that users has access.

Example:

User 1 - Mike that has,Role 1 - Admin, wich has access for the pages 1 - Home, 2 - Post and 3 - Dashboard, now I need to list the permissions for each page..

Can you help me coding?

Thank and sorry for my bad english

Comment: you need to get help from Laravel 5.3 Authorization page. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization

Answer (score 0):

I thank you can get pages from user trying something like this:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find( Auth::user()->id );
//
foreach( $user->roles as $user_role ) {
  $user_pages = $user_role->pages;
  //...
}
```

look this part of documentation, maybe will help you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are listing the pages that the users has access

How can you get the permissions of that pages?

Did you see the picture of the tables?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

you can use **spatie/laravel-permission** package for this